# Match everything that comes before a character, if there is one (Regex)

Tags: regex, logstash-grok, grok

Good evening guys!

I wrote a pattern that catches resource:

```
X-ray Tracing ID : Root=%{DATA:resource}
```

In the log excerpt below:

```
(d9be2aec-d683-4d9b-8d3c-428f1f339416) X-ray Tracing ID : Root=1-612dd69a-4b2951db368113005fb367ce
```

However, I am considering a case when an additional fragment after @ appears in the logs, which I would not like to take into account:

```
(d9be2aec-d683-4d9b-8d3c-428f1f339416) X-ray Tracing ID : Root=1-612dd69a-4b2951db368113005fb367ce@12345678998765
```

This is where the grok works that I wrote:

```
X-ray Tracing ID : Root=%{DATA:resource}[^@]*
```

And how to combine these two cases? Similar syntax, except that if @ appears we do not take into account the rest, and if it does, and if it does not, we take all of it?

I am a beginner in grok patterns so would appreciate a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Grok patterns, you will see `DATA .*?`. If your pattern ends with this construct, it won't match anything as lazy patterns at the end of regex never consume any text.

I suggest matching all chars other than whitespace and `@` here with `(?<resource>[^[:space:]@]+)` rather than using the `DATA` pattern:

```
X-ray Tracing ID : Root=(?<resource>[^[:space:]@]+)
```

See the test screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wiktor,

Indeed, a good idea, now wondering how to get rid of the @ ending if it shows up (and doesn't always show up) I'm looking for a pattern that would satisfy these two cases

Comment: @Dawid That was not actually clear, I thought you wanted to get the rest of the chars after `Root=`. So, you need a custom pattern, `X-ray Tracing ID : Root=(?<resource>[^[:space:]@]+)`